how can i solve the problem that property_graph_store.json can not be saved as utf8?[LammaIndex]
When I use the propertygraphindex to persist to disk， the other file such as default__vector_store.json saved as utf8 because it uses the json.dump(assic=True) when vector_store.persist() is called.But the property graph.persist use the model_dump_json() when its persist() is called, the model_dump_json() does not have the assic=True parameter to cover the Chinese to the format like \u6235
So how can I solve this problem, only the property_graph_store.json file can not be saved as utf-8.
I've tried a lot of things to no avail
